# Solve the following recurrence relation in two variables

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, alternative-proof

How to solve this recurrence 
$$S(m,n)=S(m,n-1)+S(m-1,n-1)+S(m-1,n)$$
 with  base conditions  $$S(1,1)=3,\; S(0,n)=S(m,0)=1.$$

---

This  recurrence came up when I tried to solve this problem: Find the number of paths from lower most left corner to uppermost right corner if one can move horizontally, vertically and diagonally. I have a combinatorial solution but want it through this recurrence.

Comment: $S(m,1)=m\Rightarrow S(1,1)=1$ which contradicts the last piece of information.

Comment: I have updated it 
Actually the recurrence when I tried to solve this problem: 
Find the no. of paths from lower most left corner to uppermost right corner if one can move horizontally, vertically and diagonally. 
I have a combinatorial solution but want it through this recurrence

Comment: Are we assuming that $S(0,n)=S(m,0)=0$?

Comment: @Tanay If you have a combinatorial solution, then don't you have a solution to the recursion?  Do you need help showing them to be equal?

Comment: @Math1000 The initial condition would be $S(0, n) = S(m, 0) = 1$

Comment: I added those to your post @DanielV

Comment: @DanielV I want a solution of the recurrence relation in th way they are solved, probably by generating functions. I don't have the required knowledge to solve it. The combinatorial reasoning that I have is as follows : Suppose you don't make diagonal movements then the number of paths are (m+n)!/m!n! (consider H as horizontal and V as vertical movement then paths are permutations of m H and n V movements). Now, if diagonal moves are used then number of permissible moves is 0<=k<=min(m,n) and one such move is a HV subsequence in the permutation of m H's and n V's.

Comment: A valid (difficult) math question, 5 users voted to close, none of them left a comment as far as why.  That isn't what the close button is for.  Btw, if you use generating functions, then you get that $$S(m, n) = \dfrac{1}{m!~n!}~\left(\dfrac{\partial^{m + n} f}{\partial^m x ~\partial^n y}\right)(0, 0)$$
 for
 $$f(x, y) = \dfrac{1}{1 - x - y - xy}$$ which isn't much easier.